# Перегрузка оператора приведения в базовый класс

Tags: c++

Потребовали внезапно в производном классе перегрузить оператор приведения в базовый(это лаба, сам бы такое не стал делать).

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

};

class B: public A {
    operator A() {
        std::cout << "operator A()\n";
        A a;
        return a;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A a = (A)b;
}
```

При запуске ничего не выводит - т.е перегрузку не вызывает. Знакомые сказали что скорее всего не выйдет перегрузить так оператор. Хотелось бы что бы кто-то более подробно рассказал почему так не выйдет делать и что по этому поводу пишет стандарт.

Comment: я бы попросил преподавателя показать как он хочет вызывать этот оператор. А то может он просто хочет функцию вида `A b2a(B b){}`

Answer (score 0):

Класс наследник может сам копироваться в свой базовый класс, это называется *срезка*.

Если изменить наследование на `class B: private A {`,
то мы увидим ошибку компиляции `error: 'A' is an inaccessible base of 'B'`.
Т.е. компилятор пытается сделать срезку, и игнорирует оператор приведения.

Вывод - нельзя написать такой оператор приведения.

Comment: Оказывается все-таки можно. Только вызывать надо по-другому. 
A a = b.operator A();